# Android Room InvalidationTracker and Flow stream not notified on @Update

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

It seems that InvalidationTracker and Flow results are not notified on @Update Dao method call for changing entity in Android Room.

Is it ok behaviour. So updating attributes of entities should not emit new values via Flow stream? InvalidationTracker not being called about changed in Entity table is good for my solution but not emitting value is a little bit odd for me.

Comment: Yes, it's odd indeed. But maybe something hides in details of your specific implementation. Can you check your theory with adding one more query method with the same SQL but with LiveData wrapper? Will it be triggered?

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-flow) say: _Whenever any of the data in the table changes, the returned Flow object triggers the query again and re-emits the entire result set._ (version 2.2)

Comment: I've found it it notifies both! Reason was I have rowid autoincremented and objects id with unique index